# Susy 2.0 responsive grid

Tags: susy-sass, susy

I'm converting a layout from Susy 1 to Susy 2.0 and have some things working differently than expected. Am I doing something wrong here? I would like the container to span the width of the page and have a column half the width be in the middle of the page. Inside of that column, 3 equally spaced columns(red, white and blue). I'm not sure how the css is compiling as it is in the screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

```
header {  
.fullheight {
    @include backImage('../images/img_hero_brightspace-homepage.png');
    @include container(100%);
    .hgroup {
      padding: 150px 0;
      text-align: center;
      h3{
        @include span(8);
        display: block;
        font-weight: $light;
      }
    } //hgroup
    section{
      @include container;
      @include span(6 at 3 of 12);
      .serviceBox{
      @include span(2 of 6);
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        background-color: white;
      }//serviceBox
       .volunteerBox{
      @include span(2 of 6);
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        background-color: blue;
      }//volunteerBox
      .partnerBox{
      @include span(2 of 6);
        width:100%;
        height:40px;
        background-color: red;
      }//partnerBox
    }
  } //fullheight
} //header
```

My Susy Template

```
$susy: (  
  columns: 12,
  container: 60em,
  gutters: 1/4,
  gutter-position: inside
);
```

My HTML

```
<article class="fullheight">
  <div class="hgroup">
    <h3>Providing help to residents of Greater Cincinnati when challenges invade their lives</h3>
   </div>

  <section>
    <div class="serviceBox">

    </div>
    <div class="volunteerBox">

    </div>
    <div class="partnerBox">

    </div>       
  </section>      
</article>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues here, but mainly you just have too much code. You don't want to use both `container` and `span` on the same element (one overrides the other), and the same is true for setting a `span` and then a css `width`. There would be several ways to implement the layout you want, but here's the one I'd recommend based on what I see:

```
section{
  @include container(6);

  .serviceBox{
    @include span(2 of 6);
    height:40px;
    background-color: white;
  }//serviceBox

  .volunteerBox{
    @include span(2 of 6);
    height:40px;
    background-color: blue;
  }//volunteerBox

  .partnerBox{
    @include span(2 of 6);
    height:40px;
    background-color: red;
  }//partnerBox
}
```

As a side note, it's considered bad practice in Sass to nest everything to match the DOM. Nesting is great when you need it, but the less you use it the better — because deep nesting creates long CSS selectors, and high specificity.